# Requiring module "node_modules\@react-navigation\drawer\src\index.tsx" while using Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am working on building a React Native application. I have installed React navigation stack and worked on it, it works fine. When I installed Drawer navigation and tried to use that, it came up with these errors. What is causing the problem here?

My App.js:

[image]

My Navigation.js:

[image]

My Errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`npm start -- --reset-cache`

Also I closed and rerun the emulator.

More can me found here.
[Navigate](https://lifesaver.codes/answer/unable-to-resolve-module-react-navigation-native)